# Derive new column from stream

Tags: scala, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading data from Kafka using Spark Structured Streaming and I am trying to create a new column based on the content of a list.

I model my data like so:

```
case class Product(properties: List[Property])
case class Property(code: String, value: String)
```

And I read like this:

```
spark
  .readStream
  .load()
  .select($"value".cast("STRING").as("value"))
  .select(from_json($"value", schema).as("product").as[Product])
  .withColumn("articleType", when(array_contains($"properties.code", "ATY"), $"properties.value")
```

This approach creates a new column named 'articleType' containing all property values when 'ATY' is present, but I only want the value for the ATY value to be in the column.

Basically I would like to do something like this

```
properties.filter(_.code == "ATY").map(_.value)
```

I'm fairly new to Spark so maybe this is not the right approach, but any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this using a udf.

```
val getArticleType = udf((properties: Seq[Row]) => {
  properties.size.toString
  properties.find(_.getString(2) == "ATY").map(_.getString(1))
}, StringType)
```

And use it like this:

```
.withColumn("articleType", getArticleType(col("properties")))
```